# Unable to Connect Keycloack Container with Other Containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to connect the keycloak container (I'm using quay.io/keycloak), to some API that are running inside another container. Locally everything is running just fine (with localhost), but when I try to connect a container with keycloak it alwasys returns connection refused and It throws this exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder]: Factory method
> 'jwtDecoder' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve the
> Configuration with the provided Issuer of
> "http://keycloak-authorization-server:8080/realms/microservices-realm"

Here is my keycloak docker:

```
services:
  keycloak-authorization-server:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: mykeycloak2
    hostname: keycloak-server
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL: DEBUG
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_USER: user_1
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

And this is my services-docker:

```
services:
  elastic-query-service-1:
    image: ${GROUP_ID}/elastic.query.service:${SERVICE_VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "5008:5008"
      - "8183:8183"
    volumes:
      - "./docker-logs:/workspace/elastic-query-service/logs"
      - "./check-config-server-started.sh:/usr/local/bin/check-config-server-started.sh"
    user: root
    entrypoint: [ "check-config-server-started.sh" ]
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5008 -Xms128m -Xmx256m"
      - "LOGGING_LEVEL_COM_MICROSERVICES_DEMO=info"
      - "LOGGING_LEVEL_ROOT=info"
      - "ELASTIC-CONFIG-DATA_INDEX-NAME=twitter-index"
      - "ELASTIC-CONFIG-DATA_CONNECTION-URL=elastic-1:9200"
      - "SERVER_PORT=8183"
      - "SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT-PATH=/elastic-query-service"
      - "SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://config-server:8888"
      - "ENCRYPT_KEY=${ENCRYPT_KEY}"
      - "SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_ISSUER-URI=http://keycloak-authorization-server:8080/realms/microservices-realm"
      - "SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_RESOURCESERVER_JWT_JWK-SET-URI=http://keycloak-authorization-server:8080/realms/microservices-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs"
      - "SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_KEYCLOAK_TOKEN-URI=http://keycloak-authorization-server:8080/realms/microservices-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token"
      - "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://172.20.0.2:5432/postgres?currentSchema=public&binaryTransfer=true&reWriteBatchedInserts=true"
    networks:
      - ${GLOBAL_NETWORK:-services}
```

I ommited some containers from the services because they are working just fine. I've tried with localhost but got the same error, what am I missing?

Comment: You have those two services defined in _separate_ `docker-compose.yml` files?

Comment: Yes. Now looking at the docker-compose they are running in different networks, one runs in a  bridge network and the keycloak runs on the default network... Should I test running all in the same network?

Comment: I suggest putting both services in the same `docker-compose.yml` and ensuring that they are on the same network.